# Kubuntu 15.04 HDMI to LCD works, HDTV does not

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, 15.04, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I've been at if for hours with no joy on this one so I'm posting my first question ever tonight.

New install of Kubuntu 15.04 on a Dell Precision M6600 with nVidia Quadro 3000M video.

- Samsung LCD monitor via HDMI connection works great.
- Samsung HDTV goes black after bootsplash and login then to sleep mode as if not connected.
- Error dialog: "plasma has stopped" appears after a few seconds.

In display settings, the TV is listed but is not active.
In nVidia settings TV is listed but shows as "off".

Thanks in advance for any help on this!

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by installing Gnome.

```
apt-get install gnome
```

Kubuntu 15.04 comes with Plasma desktop which was failing just after logging in.

As stated above, the error simply said "Plasma has stopped". Trying to use the debug option yielded no useful information.